# How to make loop values collected in array available outside the loop for future use

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have fetch values of multiple checkbox from form ,and collected in an  array,which is now available inside the current for loop ,but i want that array to be used for future purpose outside the loop.
Right now i am getting all values in loop only.
but when i print the same array outside for  loop it is displaying only the last value in an array.

```
 <script>
    function submitform(path){
            var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i=0 ; i< ele.length ; i++ )
            {
                arr['arr2'] = ele[i].value;
            }
           console.log(arr);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Try to give array out of function. in global scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing the same variable with another value in each cycle of the for loop, by executing `arr['arr2'] = ele[i].value;`

As result your array will contain only one value at the end.

**Solution**: Use the increment variable `i` of the for loop as array index.

```
function submitform(path){
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0 ; i< ele.length ; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = ele[i].value;
    }
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: I would consider using `arr.push(ele[i].value);` instead of `arr[i] = ele[i].value;` but only because I think it's more clear what you're actually doing. Some quick searching hints about `push` being faster as well, but cant' really tell since jsperf is down.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: @HenrikAronsson yes..but only if the number of elements are large..  I think in this case it will not even touch 10 I suppose so performance will be negligible.. If its > 1000 push will perform better

Answer (score 1):

```js
function submitform(path){
        //var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
        var ele = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
        var arr = new Array();
        for(var i=0 ; i< ele.length ; i++ )
        {
            arr.push(ele[i]);
        }
       console.log(arr);
    }
 submitform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use push to make an array of loop values and use new array outside of loop

```
var OurElements = document.getElementById("ID");
var arr = [];//Make empty array
for (i=0;i<=OurElements.length;i++){
    arr.push(OurElements[i]);
}
console.log(arr);//Get array on console
console.log(arr.stringify);//This return array as strings, then you can save all data on variable
```